# Slow XSSFWorkbook and WorkbookFactory when reading xlsx files

Tags: performance, apache-poi, xlsx, xssf

I've seen developers have had this problem since a few years ago. I have studied many forums and the official POI documents. Nonetheless I haven't found an answer yet. 
So the problem is.. I have tried the following two snippets:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("spreadsheet.xlsx"));
```

and

```
File file = new File("C:\\spreadsheet.xlsx");
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file.getAbsolutePath());
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

and either of the approaches takes about 5-6min (if the application doesn't run out of memory) to process a simple and fairly small spreadsheet.xlsx file (200KB).

What do I need to do to fix this? (I'm using Apache POI 3.9)

```
/*****************************/
```

The process takes a long time in the following location:

```
public class XSSFSheet extends POIXMLDocumentPart implements Sheet{
...
protected void read(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    try {
      -->>> worksheet = WorksheetDocument.Factory.parse(is).getWorksheet();
    } catch (XmlException e){
        throw new POIXMLException(e);
    }
}
...
```

I can't debug further. The VisualVM also says the same thing..!

Comment: I've just tried on my machine with a 305kb .xlsx file, with a few hundred mb Java heap, and POI opened it in under a second! I can only suggest you double check you really are running the version of Apache POI you think you are, then use a profiler to see where the time is going

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr. I'd already increased the heap size to 512mb. I have about 25000 rows of data, and each row has 20 columns (just use 111 in each cell). This takes quite some time. In a real situation I will have 50K+ rows of data.

Comment: I opened `xlsx` files with over 30k lines and 100+ columns under a few seconds. I have no idea how it can be so slow for you. I would suggest you try profiling with [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) and see what causes it to be so slow.

Comment: On my machine, using SSPerformanceTest, I can generate a 25k row 20 column .xls file in 3 seconds, and a .xlsx one in 7 seconds. I then used ToCSV to make read it in with HSSF or XSSF and generate a CSV, with the .xls it took 4 seconds, with .xlsx it took 9 seconds. So, the problem still seems to be at your end, not with Apache POI!

Comment: xlsx generation is pretty fast. It's just the read that I'm having problems with. I tried it on two different boxes and got the same results. So I wanna make sure all of you have used the code snippet I posted above to read the files!

Answer (score 1):

One factor that might be contributing to the load time is that the data has been pasted into the worksheet so that the used range includes every row, ie when you use the sheet.usedrange rows count it returns > 1,000,000 rows..  Not sure how this happens but I found that I needed to perform an intermediary step wherein prior to loading the workbook I 'cleaned' it by using some vba script.  The workbook has around 20 sheets of around 5000 rows each, each of which are filled out by different parts o the business, and it takes a fairly long time (maybe 4 minutes) to load but that is acceptable in this case.  Before I added the cleaning stage it ran for over 30 minutes, which was not acceptable....

A user runs the process I am referring to, bu pressing two buttons.  The first cleans, the second does the rest.  The first process is triggered using Runtime.getruntime.exec  and creates an empty text file that the second process will not run unless the test file is there.