# XSSFWorkbook takes a long time to load. How long should it take?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I have seen plenty of similar questions but none of the solutions work for me.

I am trying to load a .xlsx file with 8 columns and 3 rows. There is just numbers in the cells and nothing else in the file. It's taking over 10 seconds to load this file. Any idea why?

```
        File file1 = new File("C:\\Projects\\SafeSiteLive\\web\\images\\safesite_documents\\1\\sampleData2.xlsx");
        double time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);
        double endTimme = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time took to parse excel file: " + (endTimme - time));
```

The time outputted here is around 15 seconds. Surely that's too long? 
In the end I want to be loading files with 1000 rows but at the moment this takes way too long.

Time output "Time took to parse excel file: 15039.0"

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1.Depends on the hardware
2. Can you print the time? (maybe its millsec instead of sec)
Consider this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051802/slow-xssfworkbook-and-workbookfactory-when-reading-xlsx-files

Comment: Here is the time "Time took to parse excel file: 15039.0"

I just created the excel file and entered the data in, there is not other data or anomalies in the file.

Comment: version of POI you are using?
Its mostly not an API problem, but rather a hardware issue, try using a profiler

Comment: But don't you need a XSSFWorkbook to construct an SXSSFWorkbook?

Comment: Have you tried to convert your Excel (XLSX) to (old) XLS? Maybe this can help you in any way...

Comment: Did you try following the instructions in the [Apache POI FAQ on memory and performance](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109)?